# Issues running pip command

Tags: centos, python

I am running Centos 6.10. My pip version is 7.1.0. When I run pip. I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pip._internal import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cmdoptions.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 536
    {str(c.version) for c in all_candidates},
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here are the things that I have tried in order to fix it:

- sudo yum reinstall python-pip
- using pip to upgrade (which doesn't work because pip does not)

Has anyone else had this issue and have you been able to fix it?

Comment: Related: http://www.andrew-kirkpatrick.com/2018/04/centosrhel-6-python-pip-error-syntaxerror-invalid-syntax-strc-version-c-all_candidates/

Answer (score 0):

Try installing pip3. On centos it goes like this.

```
$ sudo yum install -y python34-setuptools
$ sudo easy_install-3.4 pip
```

You may need to change 3.4 to 3.6 or to the most recent python3 version.

Notice that you will end with more than one version of pip, and that you should explicitly select the non-default pip. In my system, I have (type `pip<TAB><TAB>`):

```
$ pip
pip     pip2    pip2.7  pip3    pip3.6
```

pip3 is the default for my system (OpenSuse):

```
$ pip -V
pip 18.0 from /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)

$ pip2 -V
pip 18.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

So in my case, I must explicitly do `pip2 <something>`. Please check your defaults.

Reference:

[1] https://gist.github.com/diegopacheco/ee7ac81deb6e33a8cf7ae9f674e0df6a